# GraphQL/APOLLO - Cannot query field "field_name" on type "Query"

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am trying to make a query like this in the latest apollo/server 4.9 and graphqlClient - 3.7 like below:

```
const USER_DATA = gql`
query getUserData($subdomain: String!) {
getUserData(subdomain: $subdomain) {
  _id
  full_name
  email
  valid_complex_password
  projects {
    _id
    image_url
    title
    description
    street_address
    city
    province
    country
  }
 }
}
```

but keep getting this:

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Cannot query field \"getUserData\" on type \"Query\".",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3
            }
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
            "stacktrace": [
                "GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"getUserData\" on type \"Query\".",
                ......
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

**This same query used to work fine with older version of apollo server/client and graphql. Post upgrade it started breaking without any changes to schema etc.**

Anything that needs to be changed in the way this is queried or I am missing something?

Migrated from

```
"apollo-server-errors": "^3.3.1",
"apollo-server-express": "^2.16.1",
"apollo-upload-server": "^7.1.0",
"graphql": "^14.6.0",
"graphql-compose": "^7.17.0",
"graphql-compose-aws": "^4.0.1",
"graphql-compose-connection": "^6.2.0",
"graphql-compose-mongoose": "^7.3.8",
"graphql-middleware": "^4.0.2",
"graphql-redis-subscriptions": "^2.2.2",
"graphql-tools": "^4.0.8",
```

To

```
"@apollo/server": "^4.9.5",
"graphql": "^16.8.1",
"graphql-compose": "^9.0.10",
"graphql-compose-aws": "^5.3.0",
"graphql-compose-connection": "^8.2.1",
"graphql-compose-mongoose": "^10.0.0",
"graphql-middleware": "^6.1.35",
"graphql-redis-subscriptions": "^2.6.0",
"graphql-subscriptions": "^2.0.0",
```

Comment: 1. Do other queries still work? 2. The server is returning this message correct? 3. Do queries still work from GraphiQL/Apollo Studio?

Comment: No, Yes and No!

Comment: ok, so server is where it's at. What did you migrate to 4.9 from?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Please see my edit. Added where from we migrated to! Hope that helps

Comment: Apollo v4 is a pretty big migration from 3.x even and it looks like you jumped up from 2.x! You have a lot of [work](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/) in front of you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you've migrated across 2 versions of breaking changes in Apollo-server. You'll need to [migrate](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/) your project to get it to work in the apollo-server v4.x world.

If you're not using express to serve any other content I suggest just using apollo-server and ditching express. The model for using Apollo with express is quite different in v4.

Comment: hmm, I think you are right! I just joined this project as a replacement lead and can't stand these so much outdated deps. Will go through the grind then - but by all means update all this